# Fill NaN values with values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have data that look like this:

```
Time Rain1Hour Rain6Hour
0    0         NaN
1    1         NaN
2    1         NaN
3    1         NaN
4    1         NaN
5    1         NaN
6    1         NaN
7    0         NaN
```

Where Rain1Hour is the rain in the last hour and Rain6Hour is the accumulated rain in the last 6 hours, which means I want the sum of the rain in the last 6 hours using the data from the Rain1Hour column. How do I fill the column Rain6Hour with the data from Rain1Hour. I want it to be like:

```
Rain6Hour
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
5
```

For example, the fourth row is 3 because it has been raining a quantity of 1 each hour the previous 3 hours and a quantity of 0 in the hour 0.

I am using Python and the data is in a Pandas dataframe.

EDIT: After solving the question using the rolling function that lcrmorin mentioned, I have now another one closely related to this. Is it possible to only sum over some specific rows? For example, if I am currently in time 6, I want to sum the value of the rows time=6, time=6-2, and time = 6-4, of the column Rain1Hour and assign it to another column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814201/pandas-rolling-gives-nan you are looking for the rolling function and the min_period keyword

Comment: @lcrmorin Thank you! That what I was looking for. I have now a related question, do you know if it would be possible to only sum over some specific rows? For example, if I am currently in time 6, I want to sum the value of the rows time=6, time=6-2 and time = 6-4, of the column Rain1Hour.

Comment: I think you can build custom functions... but not sure how (agg key ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) function together with the [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) function, as such:

```
df['Rain6Hour'] = df['Rain1Hour'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=6).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use custom index lists with the .rolling() method either, but you try using the .shift() method.  The option fill_value in .shift() will help you avoid NaN issue.  For instance, to create a column that is sum of (time k) + (time k-2) + (time k-4):

```
df['0_2_4']=df['1hr']\
            +df['1hr'].shift(2,fill_value=0)\
            +df['1hr'].shift(4,fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
# fill missing values in Rain6Hour with shifted values from Rain1Hour
df['Rain6Hour'] = df['Rain6Hour'].fillna(df['Rain1Hour'].shift(5))
```

Comment: I think that function does not do what I want, I think using that I am just putting the values of the column 'Rain1Hour' in 'Rain6Hour' but with a delay of 5, what I want is, for each row, sum every value in the current and the previous 5 rows of the column 'Rain1Hour' and write it in 'Rain6Hour'.